# java read only character by System.in

Tags: java, string

If the user enters "hello" via keyboard, he must give an error and request the data again.  the keyboard data will only be correct if it contains only one character.

```
public static String datoStringChar() {
    //En caso de introducir mas de una letra volver a pedir dato.
    // Entorno:
    InputStreamReader br;

    char letra;
    boolean esCorrecto;
    //Algoritmo
    letra = '0';
    br = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
    try {
        do {
            letra = (char) br.read();
            esCorrecto = true;
        } while (!esCorrecto);
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.err.println("Error I/O");

    }
    return Character.toString(letra);
}
```

Comment: You cannot limit the input from the standard Java console as you're requesting. Use a 3rd party console or a GUI for this.

Comment: I want to do is that if the user enters more than one character, I will ask you again for data until it has one character.